# Master page Client ID

Tags: asp.net

Master page's client ID is not getting attached to my asp.net Controls Client ID , It is getting attached on local development server as well as on client server but not getting attached on my testing server , Two days back it was generating properly("ct100_content_controlid"), but now it is "content_controlid". does any one can let me what would the problem and how can i solve this?

Comment: If you can share bit of your code and what exactly trying to do, may be we can help you out?

Answer (score 0):

Did you change which version of the .NET Framework you're using on one machine vs. the other?

There was a change to the default client ID mode between .NET 3.5 and 4.0, I think.

If this is a problem for your JavaScript, consider emitting `Control.ClientID` dynamically, rather than hard-coding the ID names.